# MyISAM engine error but the DB is all InnoDB

Tags: wordpress, database

On my install CiviCRM runs in a separate database that is entirely InnoDB, but Civi throws up the MyISAM engine error anyway.  The rest of wordpress lives in a DB that is InnoDB by default, although the tables are a mix of the two types, but I don't see why that matters. So why am I getting the MyISAM Engine error in Civi?

Versions: CiviCRM 4.7.11, wordpress 4.6.1, PHP 5.6.24, MySQL 5.0.11

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in CiviCRM 4.7.12 with this commit: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/2475b5509e9638fa2e9863256348c5415f362b72

Cheers,
Olivier;

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this warning pop up a couple of times in the last month. My CiviCRM database is InnoDB but I notice Wordpress is MyISAM. Clearing Civi's cache clears the message. I believe Wordpress can be converted to InnoDB, so I will investigate that.

Wordpress 4.9.8, CiviCRM 5.6.0, MySQL 5.7.23, PHP 7.1.22

Comment: I did convert Wordpress to InnoDB with no effect on the error, but I did trace the issue in CiviCRM to the Contribution Details report. When I run the report, I get a "civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_..." table for each page of output. Those tables are MyISAM, which is the default_storage_engine on my host (I can't change it). The error then appears, although it doesn't seem to hurt anything. It, and the tmp tables, go away when I clear cache.

Comment: I found a similar issue mention on Jira: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-8225